# Google analytics: specific cross subdomains tracking

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, analytics, tracking, subdomain

I have 3 sites:
* http://www.example.com 
* http://aaa.example.com
* http://bbb.example.com

I want `www`& `aaa` to be displayed in the same Google Analytics report.
I want `bbb` to be considered as a "referral source" for `www` and `aaa`.

Is it possible?

My guess:
* Use 2 different tracking codes
* Enable cross subdomains tracking for `www` and `aaa` via `_gaq.push(['setDomainName','example.com'])`

My only fear: I'm not sure if cross domain tracking on `www` and `aaa` will count visits to `www` from `bbb` as referrals (what I want) or direct (what I don't want).

What do you think?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd make this a comment not an answer, but I don't have 50 reputation points yet

I don't know if this is doable, have you tried asking on the [GA product forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/analytics)?

You should be able to filter out the traffic from a given subdomain(s) using profile filters; perhaps you could also emulate referrals using filters? Might be worth a look into it